# Magento 2 : Fatal error - Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock

Tags: magento2, category, blocks, fatal-error

Here is the screenshot of error....
[image]

And here is my Block class...

```
/**
 * Categories slider get categories class file
 */

namespace MGS\Fewclicks_startsite_category\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use MGS\Fewclicks_cron_activation_reminder\Controller\Index;

class CategoriesCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

protected $_categoryHelper;
protected $categoryFlatConfig;
protected $categoryFactory;
protected $categoryRepository;
protected $sendMail;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper = null, \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory = null, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState = null , CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository = null , \MGS\Fewclicks_cron_activation_reminder\Controller\Index\Sendmail $sendMail = null 
) {
    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->sendMail = $sendMail;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCategoryHelper() {
    return $this->_categoryHelper;
}

public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT ccev.entity_id as id,ccev.value as name,
            ccev2.value as img
            FROM catalog_category_entity as main_table
            LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar as ccev
            ON ccev.entity_id=main_table.entity_id AND ccev.attribute_id =45

            LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar as ccev2
            ON ccev2.entity_id=main_table.entity_id AND ccev2.attribute_id =48

            INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity_int as ccei
            ON ccei.entity_id=main_table.entity_id AND ccei.attribute_id =46  AND ccei.value = 1

            GROUP BY ccev.entity_id
            ORDER BY main_table.level asc,main_table.parent_id asc,ccev.value asc";

    $results = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    $this->sendMail();
    return $results;
}

public function getChildCategories($category) {
    if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource()) {
        $subcategories = (array) $category->getChildrenNodes();
    } else {
        $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
    }
    return $subcategories;
}

public function getImageUrl($categoryId) {
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    return $category->getImageUrl();
}

public function getCategoryURL($categoryId) {
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    return $category->getUrl();
}
}
```

And here is my di.xml...

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="MGS\Fewclicks_startsite_category\Block\CategoriesCollection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="deleteorderAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="context" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context</item>
                <item name="helper" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category</item>
                <item name="flatstate" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State</item>
                <item name="menu" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

  <!-- <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Autocomplete\DataProvider" type="Fewclicks\SmartSearch\Model\Autocomplete\SearchDataProvider" /> -->
</config>
```

can anyone suggest where in constructor my sequence of parameter goes wrong...as i have seen that above error is due to required and optional parameter sequence issue...as per the [Magento 2 - Object manager tries to instantiate Abstract class. ( Fatal error )](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76584/magento-2-object-manager-tries-to-instantiate-abstract-class-fatal-error)

Please suggest me regarding this.Thanks in advance....

Comment: please post the complete class definition and di.xml if you are using it to overwrite any class.

Comment: I have updated  di.xml and complete block class code in the question...

Answer (score 4):

The following command will helps you.
Please Run Upgrade Command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

check it out by running

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

if the above cli command is not working then

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

if any file permission error then make file permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/ var/cache
```

File permission 777 is not so good idea but for your error you can check it out.