# Magento2 : purchased Theme inside testimonial module using when add testimonial than getting error

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, custom-theme

I am using magento2 and purchased theme inside testimonial module enable after add testimonial than frontend side getting error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Rokanthemes\Testimonial\Controller\Form\Index in /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Rokanthemes\\Tes...', Array) #1 /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Rokanthemes\\Tes...', Array) #2 /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Rokanthemes\\Tes...') #3 /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(297): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Rokanthemes\\Tes...') #4 /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(158): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Obje in /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

If any one idea please reply me this error comes only live environment in staging working add testimonial functionality.

below my file path Rokanthemes/Testimonial/Controller/Form

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 tokitheme.com. All rights reserved.

* @author Blue Sky Team <contact@tokitheme.com>
*/

namespace Rokanthemes\Testimonial\Controller\Form;

abstract class Index extends \Rokanthemes\Testimonial\Controller\Form {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Renders CMS Home page
     *
     * @param string|null $coreRoute
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function execute($coreRoute = null)
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('testimonialform');
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this link if that's relevant to you **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76584/magento-2-object-manager-tries-to-instantiate-abstract-class-fatal-error**

Comment: but actually in my custom module inside and there is diffrent

Comment: in live site not working this module but staging working

Comment: did try removing cache and deploying commands?

Comment: In which file check to in our module inside

Comment: dependency injection like you share link

Comment: mostly problem will be solved after removing cache and deploying commands.

Comment: you can check in this file **Rokanthemes\Testimonial\Controller\Form\Index**

Comment: so we are not change in model inside file for dependency injection like not added null "\Rokanthemes\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimo $resource = null,
  \Rokanthemes\Testimonial\Model\ResourceModel\Testimo\Collection $resourceCollection = null,"

Comment: please check it my update question i added file code here what i change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96251/discussion-between-mohit-rane-and-rv-singh).

Comment: please help me this issue not fix it after apply all command

Comment: please check the chat

Comment: can you please //protected $resultForwardFactory comment. and then try.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: not working again error comes

Comment: this issue abstract class may be

Comment: this theme plugin testimonial work on staging but live not working on  when i click add to testimonial than showing error